# Airflow Web UI LDAP authentication throws AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username

Tags: airflow

I have configured LDAP authentication for airflow, managed in OpenShift.

If I access the web UI, without clearing cache, after a redeployment, it throws the following error in web server.

It works after the browser cache is cleared.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 175, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/middleware/dispatcher.py", line 66, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/middleware/proxy_fix.py", line 232, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1879, in handle_exception
    server_error = handler(server_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 776, in show_traceback
    fallback=True) else 'Error! Please contact server admin'), 500
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 136, in render_template
    ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 838, in update_template_context
    context.update(func())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 368, in _user_context_processor
    return dict(current_user=_get_user())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 335, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 359, in _load_user
    return self.reload_user()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 321, in reload_user
    user = self.user_callback(user_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/auth/backends/ldap_auth.py", line 280, in load_user
    return LdapUser(user)
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 433, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 430, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/auth/backends/ldap_auth.py", line 184, in __init__
    user.username
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username
```

Am I missing out anything in airflow.cfg?